# Remove spaces between paragraphs with regex

Tags: javascript, regex

```
some code here

some code here
```

to

```
some code here
some code here
```

What is the regex to remove the spaces between each paragraph? I've been searching for a while but I couldn't find one. Some of the results would be:

```
some code heresome code here
```

but it isn't the one i'm trying to find

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: `string.replace(/\n+/g, '\n')`

Answer (score 0):

Replace multiple `\n` with single `\n`:

```js
var str = `some code here

some code here`;
console.log(str);
str = str.replace(/\n{2,}/g,'\n');
console.log(str);
```

Answer (score 0):

`replace` 1 or more `\n` (newline) characters with a single newline character:

```js
const input = `some code here

some code here


some code here
some code here




some code here`;
const output = input.replace(/\n+/g, '\n');
console.log(output);
```

Comment: Great it works! Thanks